# Trying to refresh a dropdown

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a button with a dropdown that I'm trying to refresh using jquery (on a from submit) so its dropdown list is updated to show new items.

```
<button type="button" tabindex="-1" class="fr-command fr-btn fr-dropdown" data-cmd="itemAttributeKey">
<i class="fa fa-text-height"></i>
</button>
<div class="fr-dropdown-menu" style="left: 597px; top: 37px;">
</div>
```

The button is for a WYSIWYG plugin (it adds text into the editor). I just got the coding above from the chrome inspect coding editor, thats all I could find for the button.

This coding is run when the form is submitted.

```
$(".fr-dropdown").load(location.href + " .fr-dropdown");
```

Problem is that it just breaks the dropdown instead of reloading it to add the updated item.

I have `$("#key-name-list").load(location.href + " #key-name-list");` going to a `key-name-list` div, and it updates the `li` items in that div just fine but I cant get the WYSIWYG editor button dropdown to be refreshed to show the new items.

I dont know much about jquery or js so this is all the info I have. I might be missing something. Whats wrong with the bit of coding I have that is ran when the form is submitted? Why does it break the dropdown instead of completely refreshing it.

**Update**

Here is an edit for @Guffa 's answer. What you said makes sense, I was copying coding from a long time ago and cant remember how it worked, it just had a similar functionality to what I needed so I used it.

Using your coding I get a similar result to what I had does this is before the form submit

[image]

and after.

[image]

Note how it breaks the buttons to not display anymore.

(Put this as an update because I wanted to add the images)

Answer (score 0):

The [`load` method](http://api.jquery.com/load/) doesn't replace the element, it places the content inside the element, so both codes are actually incorrect. In the case of the list it just doesn't fail because it adds another `div` inside the `div`.

You should get only the content from the loaded data, not the element itself:

```
$("#key-name-list").load(location.href + " #key-name-list li");
```

and:

```
$(".fr-dropdown").load(location.href + " .fr-dropdown option");
```

Comment: I've added an edit to show what im getting with my coding and with your coding

Comment: @user3234020: I see, when you were talking about a dropdown I thought that you meant a `select` element. As what you have is something different it won't have `option` elements. You have to check what the child items of the `.fr-dropdown` are so that you can use that in the selector. Alternatively just use `.fr-dropdown > *` to get the child elements.

Comment: I added `$(".fr-dropdown").load(location.href + " .fr-dropdown > *");` but it still does the same thing making them disappear

Comment: @user3234020: Time to get into the DOM explorer and check what element you have and what you get after loading. Perhaps there is something that is added to the elements at load time (`ready` or `load` event) that isn't added to the dynamically added elements?